# Duplicate vs. "Bigger Picture": Complete Answer vs. Lazy or Stupid

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534845/audio-to-waveform-or-spectrogram-image-without-playback-in-chrome?noredirect=1) was marked duplicate.

The <strike>duplicate</strike> [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074152/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-web-audio-api-to-sample-audio-faster-than-real-time) seems to focus on a method of extracting the audio data from an audio file, which is probably the most complicated part of answering my question, however its answer alone is not enough to answer my entire question.

I edited my question, adding code to be used as a basis, a request for source code and pointing out that I seek an answer containing the entire process rather than a part of it.

It was [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186232/247608) that bringing up an edited marked-as-duplicate question on meta was acceptable to get reviews of the edit.

I think my question is not a duplicate, however I have failed understanding documentation related to audio in the past (specifically ALSA) and my requesting the whole solution and not being able to figure out what the pieces (steps) are, finding them and connecting them on my own might be unacceptable.

**Edit:**

The duplicate-marked notification states:

> If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

The original question's answers do not fully address my question and it's unlikely that a future answer will. My question here is: was my edit enough? Or will I have to come up with new questions?

Comment: Agree it's not a dupe anymore, reopened.

Comment: Wait, you actually *read* the duplicate notification? You're going to do well on this site. :)

Comment: Agree it's not a duplicate, although I voted to close it again as "too broad". We typically don't accept "I don't understand this thing. Please write me the entire <whatever language> code to show me how to use it" type questions.